# strings command gives : No such file error

Tags: command-line, virtualbox

I'm a newbie user of Ubuntu. I am using Virtualbox to use Ubuntu. I use a shared folder called 'projects'. In Ubuntu, I go to a folder called Fibo and
right-click on it -> Open Terminal Here
and write strings test

test is .c file inside 'Fibo' folder. Even though it seems I do correctly, it gives:
strings: 'test': No such file error.
Any idea what causes this?
Thanks in advance

**Edit** When I try strings test.c   it shows codes inside test.c file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man strings`:

```
NAME
       strings - print the strings of printable characters in files.
```

A C source code file consists entirely of printable characters, so `strings test.c` prints it verbatim. On the other hand, there is no file in the directory named simply `test` (without the `.c` suffix).

Perhaps you expected there to be an executable file named `test`, **built from** the source code file `test.c`? If so, you can try to build it with

```
make test
```

or

```
gcc -o test test.c
```

If that succeeds, try `strings test` again.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that that was the problem. Thank you. I needed an executable file. It is solved.